# Open iOS notes app from a link and paste contents of clipboard

Tags: javascript, html, ios, iphone

I want to be able to open the iOS notes app on an iPhone via a link from inside a webpage or web app and automatically paste in whatever's in the clipboard, or to open a note with a string already loaded.

I know it's possible to open the notes app with a link such as this:

```
<a href="mobilenotes://">Open notes</a>
```

Is there anything that can be done by way of appending the href with a string which will appear in a note?