# Is there a native iOS Notes API?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

It's now 2 years after the latest question about native deep-linking to iOS apps.

Here's an [unanswered thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58454071/open-ios-notes-app-from-a-link-and-paste-contents-of-clipboard) from 2019.

From what I've been able to read we can deep link with `mobilenotes://` but it's hard to find any references to this. I'm currently working in Xamarin, which supports deep linking and apps like Maps and Mail, but not Notes.

Any leads?

Comment: AFAIK this is all that Notes offers for deep linking

Comment: @Jason man that sucks. I'll keep digging, appreciate your input